# How can I prevent Ubuntu from shutting down immediately when hitting shutdown key?

Tags: shutdown, mint, mate

I quite often let my computer run, lock the screen and let it download something while I'm away. When I come back, I often forget that my notebook is still running, so I press the key to turn it on.

Before, I had Ubuntu 10.04 (Gnome) which asked me if I want to shutdown when I did this while the computer was still running.

Now, I have Linux Mint 14 (MATE). When I now press the power key while the computer runs, it shuts down. How can I get the same behaviour in MATE that I had before in Gnome?

Comment: Mint is off-topic.

Comment: I'm quite sure it is rather a MATE problem / question than a Mint question.

Comment: By this logic I should ask at Ask Ubuntu about the Word problem I am having in Windows, as Word can run under Wine in Ubuntu. Down-voted.

Comment: Run mate-power-preferences and on the General tab choose what you want it to do when the power button is pressed. By this logic Ubuntu is the swiss army knife of the computing world. Up-voted.

Comment: @MikeC.: My current setting is "Ask me". But it doesn't. It simply shuts down.

Comment: Dang I just hit the power button while in session (not locked), mate 1.6 configured with "Ask me", and it shut everything down on me. I guess it should go to the [buglist](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-power-manager/issues).

Comment: Maybe the solution in this [bug report](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-power-manager/issues/23) or debian bug [694775](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=694775) could help, there is a situation where acpid doesn't notify mate-power-manager about the power button event.

Comment: @MikeC.: Thank you very much! [This](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-power-manager/issues/23#issuecomment-10336325) is the solution to my problem! I would accept your answer, when you write one. (And now I know that it is definitely not off topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ran Mint 14 Mate on my laptop for testing purposes. The problem you've pointed is indeed a bug from Mate. With Cinnamon though it all works fine regarding this issue. 
 - Of course this isn't a Ubuntu problem, but I like to point out to you that Mate still has some unexpected issues. Maybe an update will land to solve this nasty problem.

Also, the Mint-forums have no clue nor solution to solve this problem (edit)